# Trying to insert a row into my table using sql query INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a new row into my database using an `INSERT INTO` SQL query. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am not the more experienced programmer.

I am trying to add the integer value 1 to the column Question Type when the button is pressed. My primary key increments automatically so that shouldn't be a problem as all of the other columns can be NULL.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Questions (Question Type)
VALUES (1)
```

When I press OK to this query an error displays saying :

> An error occurred while trying to create the parameterized query:
>
> Error in list of function arguments: 'Type' not recognized. Incomplete parameters or column list. Unable to parse query text.

This is the code for the table I am trying to add to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (
[QuestionID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Actual answer]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Question Space] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Question Type]  INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: How about writing it as: `INSERT INTO dbo.Questions
VALUES (Null,Null,1)`

Comment: I don't use search criteria builder but a glance online suggests that error is caused when your calling code uses a table adapter that expects a SELECT query. As @X.L.Ant requested, can we see the code that is submitting this SQL transaction request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this..
If the column name has White Space, then the entire column name should be enclosed using Square Brackets ([]).

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Questions ([Question Type])
VALUES (1)
```

This is for SQL server...
if it is MySQL then use ("") or (``)

Comment: Not only whitespaces, but also any unauthorized character.

Comment: When I try this it says "Failed to get schema for this query."

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by DBMS, but I am creating a local network. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and am using sql?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server

Comment: Yes I am using an SQL server

Answer (score 3):

you not allowed to use spaces between column names. either use identifier with `double quotes` or `square braces`.`""` OR `[]`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Questions ("Question Type")
VALUES (1)
```

Comment: When I try this it says "Failed to get schema for this query."

Comment: @mot375 which database you using ? and put your table struture here

Comment: @mot375 along with the code you're using to execute that query.

Comment: 'm not 100% sure what you mean by DBMS, but I am creating a local network. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and am using sql? I don't really have any code that is related to that I am using the data grid view thingy that helps add a query for you

Comment: you are executing this query from c# or from database query panel

Comment: I added the table structure ^^

Comment: I am using Search Criteria builder

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no code (yet) with access to that table, remove the whitespace in your column names.

Comment: I agree. It sounds like you are early in your project. It's a good time to change your column names so they have no spaces in them (or other non-alpha-numeric characters like dashes or underscores). Naming them like that will give you so much grief later on.